# ignore_case in ifelse statment r?

Tags: r

is there a way to do an ifelse by ignoring case? for example if I have a `name` variable and 'example' can be 'Example' or 'EXAMPLE' I would like to pick this up as flag==1.

```
df%>%mutate(flag=ifelse((name=='example', 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(flag = +(tolower(name) %in% c('example', 'othername')))
```

You could also do:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(flag = +(grepl('^(example|othername)$', name, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

Comment: thanks, and what if ```name``` has values other than 'example'? Would I do: ```mutate(flag = +(grepl('^example$'|'^othername$', name, ignore.case = TRUE)))```

Comment: amazing, single quote needs to be outside all the name options. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

With `str_detect`, we can use modifiers

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(flag = as.integer(str_detect(name, 
               regex("example|othername", ignore_case = TRUE))))
#      name flag
#1   example    1
#2   Example    1
#3   EXAmple    1
#4     hello    0
#5       ggg    0
#6 othername    1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('example', 'Example', 'EXAmple',
     'hello', 'ggg', 'othername'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```